# Why does the Low Quality Posts review queue still have question audits?

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, review-audits, low-quality-posts

Questions got kicked out of the Low Quality Posts (LQP) review queue a while back and shunted to Triage instead. So there are not now, nor have there been for some time, any legitimate questions in the queue. Why, then, are there still audits based on questions, like the one I just [passed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7607224)? That seems entirely unnecessary and indeed counterproductive.

Comment: Ok, so the answer to this is simply "we forgot to turn them off".

Comment: @Shog9: Fair enough! The question was at least partly rhetorical, but just in case….

Comment: @Shog9 Are you going to be turning them off or did you?  Please see: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297050/low-quality-post-serving-up-really-easy-audits

Comment: @NathanOliver: They haven't been turned off yet, to my knowledge.

Comment: @Shog9: Was it re-considered or just forgotten? Just got a question as an audit in VLQQ: http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/9459892

Comment: @Shog9: Was there a regression? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315525/review-failed-for-low-quality-posts http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11039914

Comment: @Shog9 It's still happening, per [this dupe by another Nathan](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/317080/2738262).

Comment: The problem here is clearly Nathans. I'll see if I can find someone to take care of that.

Comment: @Shog9 Should I be worried?

Comment: @Shog9: I always knew I'd be first against the wall when the revolution came, but I thought it would be for a more substantial reason than my name....

Comment: @NathanOliver Notice Shog did not say *Nathan's*, but *Nathans*, e.g. multiple Nathans. You both have a 50/50 chance of being "solved"... so yes, I'd be very worried.

Comment: @Shog9 Is this still an issue today? It seems like most reviewers who think that there are only answers will think that a question is a non-answer, and thus recommend it for deletion, failing the audit.

Comment: Still an issue at the moment, @gparyani: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/20919740

Comment: @Shog9 Is there any chance it can be fixed? It seems pretty simple to simply exclude questions from LQ audits. (It's also worth noting that the user who reviewed that audit [has written a user script to identify review audits](https://github.com/normalhuman/AuditDetector), not that they're necessarily using it.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should be fixed with the next build. I added a filter to only look for answers in the Low Quality Review queue, when Triage is enabled.