# Low quality review queue, don't like audit result on this question

Tags: bug, review-audits, low-quality-posts, disputed-review-audits

I was working through the Low Quality review queue, when the following question came up:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/8028513

I voted to close as "Unclear what you're asking", since there was very little text explaining what the OP was getting at. I usually avoid doing that in subject areas I'm not well versed in, but this seemed like an easy call to me.

Can someone help me understand how this is a reasonable question?

Comment: I would tend to agree, while they show the code they have and a picture (which is great!) it wasn't clear to me what the question really wanted. Not sure how it managed a 5 score.

Comment: I would retag this as bug, since you [are not supposed to get questions on the LQRQ anymore](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289627/why-does-lqp-still-have-question-audits#comment173867_289627)

Comment: Yet another crummy audit. It turns the whole process into a guessing game, which is the converse of the point.

Comment: It's a bug that questions are even in the low quality queue like @Braiam mentioned already. I haven't seen any question audit in that queue where the appropriate action was to close. They all are looks ok audits.

Comment: Thanks all for confirming that my instincts are still OK.