# Low Quality Post Serving up Really Easy Audits

Tags: discussion, review-audits, low-quality-posts

The last couple of days all of the audits I have had in the low quality review queue have been really easy to identify as audits.  Going through the queue I get answer after answer to review and then all of the sudden a question will pop up to be reviewed.  The buttons change and give different options to pick and also the questions I have been served have been nice long and detailed questions that you can just tell from looking at it that it is a good question.

From what I can remember all of my previous audits have been on answers and I can't recall every seeing a question in the queue before. Did something change recently or have I just been lucky and getting some nice easy audits?

Comment: More reading on [easy audits](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288046/this-review-is-obviously-an-audit-is-this-a-bug/288047).

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289627/why-does-lqp-still-have-question-audits

Answer (score 3):

It made sense for LQP to have questions as audits once upon a time, when questions were actually fed into LQP to be reviewed.  Now that Triage/Help & Improvement have replaced it's need to review questions it no longer makes sense for the audits in that queue to be questions.  It should indeed be changed.

As to the questions chosen being "obviously good question", *that* isn't a problem.  When having questions is appropriate in the first place, the *design* of audits is for them to be obvious to anyone paying attention.

Comment: Indeed, every time an audit *isn't* perfectly obvious, someone comes onto Meta to complain.