# Review Failed for Low Quality Posts

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, low-quality-posts, disputed-review-audits

While reviewing **Low Quality Posts**, when I marked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34923444/does-xamarin-forms-support-periodic-background-tasks) question as off-topic, I got the warning **STOP! Look and Listen** saying that this was an audit and I have failed.

[image: Screenshot of review]

Have I done something wrong?

See review-audit **[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11039914)**

Comment: Where is the 'Inappropriate' part?

Comment: @downvoters Care to comment.

Comment: A question in the LQQ is always a review. Though I think it's also a bug.

Comment: See [Why does LQP still have question audits?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289627/why-does-lqp-still-have-question-audits)

Comment: "This post offers useful information"... Yes, of course... I think, voting to close it was perfectly ok.

Answer (score 2):

The question seems OK to me.

I'm not sure why you would vote to close it as off-topic. Maybe because the first sentence says that the user has a hard time finding documentation. This makes it look a little like a request for off-site resources, but the user does not ask for links to documentation - they're asking an objectively answerable question.

You could argue that the question is Too Broad, but I would disagree with that. It is asking if Xamarin.Forms provides a specific feature, and specifies that it is needed on two types of mobile OS-es.

So, it seems to me you were too strict when voting to close.