# Stop using questions for audits in the LQPRQ

Tags: feature-request, review-audits, low-quality-posts

Once upon a time the LQPRQ (Low Quality Post Review Queue) used to have questions in it.  Since it did it was natural to use questions as audits ([example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10811815), [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10444971)).

If we fast forward to today we now have the triage queue that handles questions and now we only have answers in the LQPRQ.  Since we never have questions it does not make sense to use questions as audits.  We already have answer audits to keep us on our toes ([example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10910604), [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10939656)).  I know that audits are not supposed to be hard to spot but this seems like it is a little to easy as right now there is never a question in the LQPRQ unless it is used as an audit.

I think we should just get rid of question audits and continue using known good answers as audits.  If we need more audit sources we could use answers that went through the queue and the outcome was Looks OK.  There would more then likely need to be some other characteristics as well but that should help to find good answers for audits.

Comment: Either this (bug?) fix needs to be done, or add a **"ha ha, you don't fool me"** button to the review system :)

Comment: If you have paid enough attention to see that it's a question then the review has probably already done its job. Leaving questions in the queue helps catch robo-reviewers.

Comment: @WaiHaLee I get that but when the audit is titled with **Question** that seems a little to easy for me.

Comment: And what are you supposed to choose when you're not a robo reviewer when the audit does not match the intent of the queue? Skip is always a valid choice of course, but what if you want to add an audit-pass notch to your history?

Comment: @Gimby Looks OK will pass the question audits

Comment: I recall seeing somewhere that question audits were supposed to already be removed from the LQPRQ, but I can't seem to find that now....